# Py.Test : Report using --cov, exclude some 'def' in report and does not show any failures

Tags: python, webdriver, code-coverage, pytest

I have functions that should be excluded from the report generated, shows as missing. Right now I get :

[image: Shot of the report]

There is nothing missing. It is reading the supporting functions, and reporting on them.

eg:

```
def is_element_present(self, how, what): 
        try: self.driver.find_element(by=how, value=what)
        except NoSuchElementException, e: return False 
        return True
```

The example given above, --cov reads the `except NoSuchElementException, e: return False` line as missing. And, I realize this is a coverage reporting tool, but shouldn't it show any failed tests as well? Rhetorical, yes, it should. But, how do I show that. I've read documents and can not find that.

Comment: If memory serves correctly, `py.test` uses `coverage.py` for coverage report. So in that regard, try look into `.coveragerc` configuration for pattern/file/lines exclusions. Link: http://nedbatchelder.com/code/coverage/config.html

Comment: If you already use `.coveragerc` configuration, please post it so we can see why they're not excluded from the coverage report.

Comment: I am using --cov. eg: `py.test --verbose --cov=01_smoke.py --cov=02_regression.py --cov-report=html 01_smoke.py 02_regression.py`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since pytest-cov plugin could pick up `.coveragerc` configuration, and recommended by [`pytest-cov`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-cov):

> For further control of coverage use a coverage config file.

Create such a file if you haven't, and within it:

```
[run]
exclude_lines =

    raise NoSuchElementException
```

And do `py.test --cov-config .coveragerc [other parameters]`. Please see http://nedbatchelder.com/code/coverage/config.html for more options. Note that you don't really explicitly add `--cov-config` if the coverage config is indeed of name `.coveragerc` (it's a default for `coverage.py` and `pytest-cov`)

I tested this solution with the following code:

`main.py`

```
def main():
    try:
        print 1 / 0
    except:
        raise Exception('test')
```

`test_main.py`

```
import unittest
import main

def test_main():
    main.main()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    testcase = unittest.FunctionTestCase(test_main)
    unittest.main()
```

And performed `py.test --cov main.py`, which gave me:

> Name    Stmts   Miss  Cover
>
> main        5      0   100%

Comment: Fast forward to 2023, `exclude_also` is preferred over `exclude_lines` as it preserves the default exclude patterns. See https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html#report-exclude-also